# What key on a Mac keyboard maps to tkinter's <Cancel> and <Pause> binding

Tags: macos, tkinter, pysimplegui

I have tkinter code that binds 2 keys.

```py
        self.TKroot.bind('<Cancel>', self._callback_main_debugger_window_create_keystroke)
        self.TKroot.bind('<Pause>', self._callback_popout_window_create_keystroke)
```

On a PC, these map to BREAK and CONTROL+BREAK.

Can't figure out how to invoke them on a Mac keyboard.  What keyboard keys do I need to press to get these 2 events to happen in tkinter?

Comment: Some tech support on mac's forums say `fn + shift + F12` https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3880265

Comment: Yea, tried that one and it didn't work.